# React boostrap carousel not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a simple carousel using react-bootstrap.
This is the simple uncontrolled carousel I'm trying to create.
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/carousel/

This is my code,

```
import React from 'react';
import Carousel1 from '../../../assets/FootTheBall_SignUpScreen_CarouselImage-01.png';
import Carousel2 from '../../../assets/FootTheBall_SignUpScreen_CarouselImage-02.png';
import Carousel3 from '../../../assets/FootTheBall_SignUpScreen_CarouselImage-03.png';
import Carousel4 from 
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Carousel';


    const Core = () => (
        <main className="core">
            <article className="left">
                <Carousel>
                    <Carousel.Item>
                        <img src={Carousel1} alt=""/>
                    </Carousel.Item>
                    <Carousel.Item>
                        <img src={Carousel2} alt=""/>
                    </Carousel.Item>
                    <Carousel.Item>
                        <img src={Carousel3} alt=""/>
                    </Carousel.Item>
                </Carousel>

            </article>
            <article className="right"></article>
        </main>

    );
    export default Core
```

The images get vertically stacked and no transition happens. What am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 8):

I also had the exact same problem. In `public/index.html` file, instead of linking to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

I changed it to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

It worked :)

Answer (score 3):

Did you linked the style files?

According to [docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/):

> Because React-Bootstrap doesn't depend on a very precise version of
>   Bootstrap, we don't ship with any included css. However, some
>   stylesheet is required to use these components. How and which
>   bootstrap styles you include is up to you, but the simplest way is to
>   include the latest styles from the CDN.

For linking add following to `index.html`:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: I dont have a index.html file, I create the project using create-react-app. Where do I place these styles then. In my index.css?

Comment: create-react-app does have an index included . It should be under public

Comment: Nope, inside `index.html` in `public` folder.

Comment: If you're using `react-helmet`, you can enclose the link tag in `Helmet` like this: `<Helmet><link rel="stylesheet" .... /></Helmet>`  Don't forget the final back slash `/` in the link tag.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did. It works fine.

### Add below line in index.js

```
import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
```

Comment: ```Module not found: You attempted to import ../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.``` This error is being displayed